# Store/Recall previous parameters to function call

Tags: c++, function, parameters, overloading, increment

## Goal

If n is supplied, square(n) should return n*n

If no parameters are supplied, square() should increment the n value from the previous call and square that.

## How do I do it?

Should I use default variable or overloaded function if there are no parameters?

My main problem is getting the increment of n from the previous call, all I can do is get the same input ('n') by adding a static but if I increment n in the square function then even if there are parameters provided it will be incremented. eg. n=7, 7*7=49, so I will return 49, but then I remove parameters from the call to square function in main, now square(); , then n should be 8, and return 8*8=64.

main.cpp:

```
void main()
{
    int num = 5;
    square(num);
    cout<<"The square is: "<<square(num)<<endl;
}
```

square.h:

```
 int square(static int n=1);
```

square.cpp

```
int square(static int n)
{
return n*n;
}
```

Comment: replace `square(num)` with `num = square(num)`...

Answer (score 1):

Use function overloading to your advantage.

In square.h:

```
extern int square();
extern int square(int n);
```

In square.cc:

```
static int lastN = 0;

int square()
{
   return (lastN+1)*(lastN+1);
}

int square(int n)
{
   lastN = n;
   return n*n;
}
```